# Unity C# movement tied to player object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am toying around with a 2d space shooter. Currently I am trying to fire a projectile forward from the ship (there is a weapon and magazine object but the statement is generally true) and send it hurling into space on its trajectory. The issue is it fires and moves forward but the `x axis` follow my ship. So I get this strange effect of the bullet going forward but left or right as I move.

My assumption was that when setting the position I was giving it a reference to the ship's position but I tried changing it to a new instance of the vector based on the current position but it still follows my ship. How do I decouple the two objects movement?

```
public void Shoot()
{
    PlayerWeaponMagazine magazineScript = magazine.GetComponent<PlayerWeaponMagazine>();
    GameObject bullet = magazineScript.UseBullet();
    PlayerWeaponBullet bulletScript = bullet.GetComponent<PlayerWeaponBullet>();
    
    //Relevant Code for spawning the bullet
    var vector3 = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y);
    
    //Assuming this is just a value now and not a reference
    bullet.transform.position = vector3;
    bullet.SetActive(true);
}
```

Code for the bullet to move:

```
void Update()
{
    timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
    if (gameObject.activeSelf)
    {
        
        //Relevant code for moving the projectile.
        gameObject.transform.position += ((bulletSpeed * Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime));
        if (timePassed > bulletLifetime)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            timePassed = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

The UseBullet() is just a pool manager (from comments)

```
public GameObject UseBullet()
{
    GameObject bullet = pool[poolIndex];
    poolIndex++;
    if (poolIndex > capacity - 1)
    {
        poolIndex = 0;
    }
    return bullet;
}
```

Adding this for clarity on the answer

```
void Start()
{
    pool = new GameObject[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);
        bullet.SetActive(false);
        //bullet.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
        pool[i] = bullet;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Vector3` is a **struct** => it **is** passed by value .. `bullet.transform.position = transform.position;` would be enough ... is the bullet nested under this object? What exactly does `magazineScript.UseBullet();` do?

Comment: @derHugo that is good to know. I was not sure I am new to C#. The nesting is `ship -> weapon -> magazine` just for ordering of objects. `magazineScript.UseBullet();` is just popping an instantiated bullet prefab out of a pool.

Comment: [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) -> **struct** in UnityEngine ... and [`struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) is always a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) (except using [new c# fanciness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/ref-struct))

Comment: As said I would suspect your bullet is a child of the object that moves.

In general you should rather make your pool not move at all but be anchored to the scene. Or alternatively make sure to unparent the object when getting it from the pool and parent it back when releasing into the pool

Comment: `Vector3` is a struct, it is always passed by value... So this question has the XY  Problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  Please edit with that in mind

Comment: @ScottishTapWater not so sound curt but XY problems are usually why people ask questions. I don't know what I don't know. It is hard to form a question with the answer in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code for this call, which is where your issue most likely lies:

```
magazineScript.UseBullet();
```

Specifically, from your description, it sounds like you're spawning the bullet as a child of the weapon (or the ship). Being a child, it will inherit (in math terms, multiply) the transform of its parents into its own.

You should be spawning (or even better, reusing) bullets outside of your ship, because once they're spawned they respond to their own physics, not their ship's physics.

Comment: I added the method for you to reference.  When you say "in math terms" does that mean even though I am setting the vector it will apply math from where I nest it?

Comment: Of course, that's the purpose of nesting objects: their transforms get multiplied together.

Comment: Ah that did fix it. When I in ran the instantiation logic I put the bullets on magazine mostly just to keep them out of view. I did not realize  there were other ramification for that.

Comment: You lead me to the correct issue. I added the logic that was in `Start()` of the `bulletPrefab`. The trouble was setting the parent. I assume that since the bullets are working in world space on there own there is no way to nest them without causing issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use instantiate for your bullets.

give your bullet a scritp in what you tell it to move in a dicection and a certain speed.

next in the script shoot instantiate the bullet prefab at a starting position (in case of ship or gun, the start possition should be at the end of a gun barrel)
like this:

```
    // Instantiate at position (0, 0, 0) and zero rotation.
    Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

see the unity documnetation for more info about insantiate and how to use it.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html